How to get a curve condition from Hölder continuous
I have read a paper (https://afm.journal.fi/article/download/134517/83089), and I have one question about the proof of necessity of Theorem 2.2 of this paper. Maybe this is an easy question, but I am stuck. Specifically, let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and $\alpha\in (0,1]$.  Fix $x_0\in \Omega$.
Define
\begin{align*}
  u(x)=\inf_\beta\int_\beta d(z,\partial\Omega)^{\alpha-1} ds(z),
\end{align*}
where the infimum is taken over all curves joining $x_0$ to $x$ in $\Omega$. There is a constant $M>0$ which does not depend on $x_0$, such that for any $x_1,x_2\in \Omega$,
\begin{align*}
  |u(x_1)-u(x_2)|
  \leqslant M|x_1-x_2|^\alpha.
\end{align*}
The paper claims that by the definition of $u$ and under the previous condition, we can have
\begin{equation*}
  \int_\gamma d(z,\partial\Omega)^{\alpha-1}ds(z)
  \leqslant M|x_1-x_2|^\alpha,
\end{equation*}
where $\gamma$ is a curve joining $x_1$ and $x_2$.
But I don't know how to get the previous inequality. However, I am sure that we can have
\begin{equation*}
  |u(x_1)-u(x_2)|
  \leqslant \int_{\gamma} d(z,\partial\Omega)^{\alpha-1} ds(z).
\end{equation*}
But it seems not really helpful.
Could you give me some ideas? Thank you!

There is a proof of this inequality on p. 205 of liked paper. What is unclear in that proof?

@IosifPinelis The authors used an entire page on p.205 to show that $u$ satisfies the condition $|u(x_1)-u(x_2)|\leqslant M|x_1-x_2|^\alpha$ for any $x_1,x_2\in \Omega$. However, they didn't give the exact process to get the curve condition from $u$. Indeed, they just said:"The definition of $u$ now yields (2.3)", where (2.3) is the curve condition. And how to get the curve condition form $u$ is the point that I am stuck.
